# json value getting it as "[object Object]"

Tags: json, angularjs, ngroute

In angularjs ng-route since my params are dynamic i'm passing it as json like as shown below

```
$scope.filmNames= {
            'films': {
                    'film': [{
                        filmName: 'ABCD',
                        filmYear: '123'
                    }, {
                        filmName: 'BCD',
                        filmYear: '145'
                    }, {
                        filmName: 'DEF',
                        filmYear: '128'
                    }]
                }
            };

'.../index.html#/admin?jsonObj='+$scope.filmNames
```

ans it succesffully sending as like

```
http://localhost:8000/index.html#/admin?jsonObj=[object Object]
```

but at the controller receiver when i tried to get it through using $routeParams like

```
var jsonObj= $routeParams.jsonObj;

console.log(JSON.stringify(jsonObj));
```

It is been printing it as `"[object Object]"`, instead of the values

can anyone please tell me solutions for this

Comment: that's an object, not json. If it were json, it's string representation would not be [object Object]

Comment: Are you sending it as a GET?

Comment: how can i recive it as json

Comment: printing let me guess IE :D?

Comment: @DhavalMarthak let me check that

Comment: *"and it successfully sending as like <code>"* that isn't successful, you don't want to send the text `[object Object]`

Comment: @DhavalMarthak when i remove stringify i'm getting without quotes like `[object Object]`

Comment: @MikeRobinson yes....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you convert an object to a string using concatentation, you get: `[object Object]`. What you actually want is to convert the object to json.

```
'.../index.html#/admin?jsonObj='+JSON.stringify($scope.filmNames)
```

Then, at the receiver, you'll want to *parse* it, not stringify it.

```
console.log(JSON.parse(jsonObj));
```

---

I suggest moving away from calling json strings "json objects", it just leads to confusion. json strings don't always represent objects.